# Changing the directory by using the path specified (path includes filename as a string)

Tags: c++, linux, string, variables

I want to change to the directory specified by the path. The filename is a string and is included in the path.

I have stored the filename in a string and I am adding this filename to the path. Next using `chdir()` I am changing to the directory specified by the path.

I know that the filename can be specified in the path itself, but I want it to do it this way because the filename will be keep on changing.

```
int main()
{
    system("echo -n '1. Current Directory is '; pwd");

    std::string filename ("1184581000.pcd");

    cout<<filename;

    chdir("/home/usrn/pcd/"+ filename"");

    system("echo -n '1. Current Directory is '; pwd");

    return 0;  
}
```

The result is:

```
error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
 chdir("/home/usrn/pcd/"+ ls"");

error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int chdir(const char*)’
chdir("/home/usrn/pcd/"+ ls"");
```

Comment: In C++17, you might use [std::filesystem::current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path).

Answer (score -1):

Syntax should be:

```
chdir(("/home/usrn/pcd/"+ filename).c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks,The errors are gone,but it is not changing the directory. I am getting the output as  1. Current Directory is /home/usrn
                                   1. Current Directory is /home/usrn

Comment: @Goalscorer - You can't `chdir` to a filename. The `chdir` is failing. Check return values.

Comment: Ok,sorry I didn't know that

Comment: @Goalscorer - Leave the filename off of the `chdir`. Also see  [Is there any way to change directory using C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1293660/608639), [How to chdir using C in Linux environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13204650/608639), etc.